# Firebase React deployment leads to empty index.html instead of webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, firebase-hosting

I am deploying older code from ~3 years which previously worked like a charm. After my latest changes, I can't seem to deploy to firebase accordingly. The website stays on its index.html and fails to load the actual app.

Maybe relevant stack:

- Yarn
- React 17
- Firebase 10.8
- Node 20

index.html:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-functions-compat.js"></script>

<script>
var firebaseConfig = {...};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.analytics();

</script>
```

firebase.json (auto-generated with firebase init):

```
"hosting": {
  "public": "build",
  ...
  "rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
],
...
```

The console error on the page says:

```
main.03424e0f.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.03424e0f.js:1:1)
```

My usual commands are:

```
yarn build
firebase deploy
```

And `firebase init` is configured without overwriting any files, rewiring all URLs to index.html.

Based on other questions and ChatGPT I tried the following things:

- I tried deleting the cache (.firebase folder) and deploying again.
- I reinstalled node_modules
- I made sure firebase.json includes the correct folder "build"
- I made sure index.html in public and build folder are the same
- I tried some versions of calling initializeApp() without the compat-packages

None of them changed the behaviour of the webpage.